# SIGSEGV when trying to launch Unity3D game

Tags: 18.04, games, steam, mono, unity3d

Here is the crash log when I try launching it via Steam, looks like something to do with the mono runtime, but I have confirmed that I have mono-runtime installed via the official 18.04.4 repository:

```
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so(+0x915de) [0x7f76711bd5de]
    /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity_Data/Mono/x86_64/libmono.so(+0x3483b) [0x7f767116083b]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890) [0x7f7675279890]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x2b1) [0x7f76738eec01]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x164931f) [0x7f7668e4831f]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x181825a) [0x7f766901725a]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x164a2eb) [0x7f7668e492eb]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x164b660) [0x7f7668e4a660]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x1675dd7) [0x7f7668e74dd7]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x1676837) [0x7f7668e75837]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x1473f38) [0x7f7668c72f38]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0xe3479c) [0x7f766863379c]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x159d82c) [0x7f7668d9c82c]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x10df998) [0x7f76688de998]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x149a793) [0x7f7668c99793]
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/amdgpu_dri.so(+0x14f1fbe) [0x7f7668cf0fbe]
    /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1(+0x7b40f) [0x7f7674b4440f]
    /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1(+0x8c6b9) [0x7f7674b556b9]
    /opt/amdgpu-pro/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1(glXQueryVersion+0x20) [0x7f7674b14fa0]
    /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity() [0xc3ee64]
    /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity() [0xc3e787]
    /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity() [0x42db1b]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f7673878b97]
    /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity() [0x42f8f1]

Debug info from gdb:

ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/viru/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
I refuse to debug myself!
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries
used by your application.

=================================================================
```

When I try to launch it via the terminal, it returns this:

```
Set current directory to /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity
Found path: /home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity
Mono path[0] = '/home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = '/home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = '/home/viru/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Pillars of Eternity/PillarsOfEternity_Data/Mono/etc'
Aborted
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting of another Unitly3D based game Wasteland 2 on Ubuntu 18.04 was also problematic for me. I also have AMD GPU. Even a call stack of the crash looked similar and ended on libmono.so. I bought the game on GOG.com but didn't find a solution on their site.

Setting of the following in the startup script of the game helped to solve the problem:

```
ulimit -n 4096
```

### If this doesn't help

Good people suggest to try another thing.

There is chance that the hard limit of the open files is lower than 4096. One can check it by calling:

```
ulimit -Hn
```

If the result is lower than 4096 then edit the */etc/security/limits.conf* to have such values:

```
username soft nofile 4096
username hard nofile 8192
```

Replace "username" with the name of your user. Re-log in in the system is required for the changes to come into effect.

This a description is a translation of the hint given by the user **EugVV** on Russian-speaking community [rutracker.org](https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5097408)